# Why is my redirect not working within PHP?

Tags: php, get, header

having trouble redirecting the user based on the $_GET

this file is called forgot.php

```
<?php 

       $mode_allowed = array('password');
       if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed) === true) {
            echo $_GET['mode'];
       } else {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
       }

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only">Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="form-emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-emailaddress>
          <button type="submit" class="btn signin">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

So based on the php code, what I believe it should do is that in the URL it should only accept http://localhost/forgot.php?mode=password

however if it's anything else then it should redirect. But what it does is if i change "mode" to something else or mode = "something" which is not in the array ($mode_allowed) then it just stays at the same page.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is the complete file.  But Try to check for any whitespace in between your lines of code especially at Line 1.  Header Location redirects doesn't work when there is whitespace.

Comment: Try like.    if (isset($_GET['mode']) && in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed)){...}

Comment: IF STILL SAME ... Print_r($_GET); or use $_REQUEST instead $_GET

Comment: Everything seems correct. Try adding this condition in your `if` clause, `&& count($_GET) == 1`

Comment: And as @devpro said, do `print_r($_GET);` or `var_dump($_GET);` and see what you're getting.

Comment: so when I do print_r($_GET); and the url is http://localhost/forgot.php?abcd          ..... the result I am getting is "Array ( [ads] => )"

Comment: when I do localhost/forgot.php?mode=sadsdas , i get this "Array ( [mode] => sadsdas )"

Answer (score 1):

Here;s your updated code.

```
<?php
$mode_allowed = array('password');
       if ((isset($_GET['mode'])) && (in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed))) {
            echo $_GET['mode'];
       } else {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
       }
?>
```

You don't need to use `=== true` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a check on the parameter value. You get mode=password, but if you get anything else, you should redirect the user to the previous page.
`header('Location:index.php');`

Or you could simply use `if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'password')`

Comment: I thought the else part take care of this scenario

Comment: You could try to compare the value of the parameter using a different method, and avoid using `===` everywhere, unless you need to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `print_r($_GET);` and check what are you getting than use condition also note I am using `trim()` for removing any extra space.

```
if (isset($_GET['mode']) && in_array(trim($_GET['mode']), $mode_allowed))
{...}
```

or if you still facing same issue than you can also use `$_REQUEST`

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['mode']) && in_array(trim($_REQUEST['mode']), $mode_allowed))
{...}
```

Comment: @jomin_georage94 what r u getting in print_r($_GET);

Comment: when I do localhost/forgot.php?mode=sadsdas , i get this "Array ( [mode] => sadsdas )"

Comment: In this example it will redirect means goto else part... And u expecting it will go into IF part???? @jomin_georage94

Comment: So what I was expecting this time was that it go through the else part of the condition , which result in redirecting the user to index.php

Comment: Check var_dump(in_array(trim($_REQUEST['mode']), $mode_allowed));  @jomin_georage94

Comment: But however what it does it it removes the form and stays on the same page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103369/discussion-between-devpro-and-jomin-george94).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was because I was calling this php tag inside body